# How to retrieve the table from .doc file using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to retrieve the table from word document with the same table structure as like in my document. i.e. I want a table with  rows and columns.

Currently I'm using a code which works fine but it gives only the texts inside the cell that is too not formatted way. Is there any possible way to get the whole table with the table structure as in my document.

Following is the code which I'm using to read table

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Table;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.TableCell;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.TableRow;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

public class TableTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String fileName="D:\\vignesh\\model.doc";

        InputStream fis=new FileInputStream(fileName);
        POIFSFileSystem fs=new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
        HWPFDocument doc=new HWPFDocument(fs);

        Range range=doc.getRange();

        for(int i=0;i<range.numParagraphs();i++)
        {
            Paragraph par=range.getParagraph(i);
            System.out.println(par.text());
        }
        Paragraph tablePar=range.getParagraph(0);
        if(tablePar.isInTable())
        {
            Table table=range.getTable(tablePar);
            for(int rowIdx=0;rowIdx<table.numRows();rowIdx++)
            {
                TableRow row=table.getRow(rowIdx);
                System.out.println("row "+(rowIdx+1)+",is table header: "+row.isTableHeader());
                for(int colIdx=0;colIdx<row.numCells();colIdx++)
                {
                    TableCell cell=row.getCell(colIdx);
                    System.out.println("column "+(colIdx+1)+",text= "+cell.getParagraph(0).text());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I need to retrieve the whole table with its cells and I have to pass that to another class that will create PDF document with that table. Any example codes to retrieve the table would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Have you tried looking at how Apache Tika uses POI to generate HTML, including tables? Is that close to what you need?